# Why do we need convex functions to define the Orlicz space?

Tags: functional-analysis, function-spaces, orlicz-spaces

I am reading Theory of Orlicz spaces by M.Rao.

My question is that : why do we need a convex function to define Orlicz spaces ? Can't we take any other type of function?

Definition of Orlicz space:

L$^\phi$ ={ $f\colon A\to R$ such that $ \int_A \phi(|f|) \,d\nu < \infty$ }
here $\phi$ is a Young function defined as 
$\phi\colon R\to R^+$ such that following holds 
(1) $\phi(x)$ is a convex function.
(2) $\lim_{x \to \infty}\phi(x)=\infty$
(3)$\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$
(4)$\phi(0)=0$

Comment: I have no background in Orlicz spaces but convexity ensures that $\phi(x) \geq 0$ making $0$ a global minimum. That seems like a very useful property especially when combined with evenness since it isolates all the interesting behavior in the non-negative quadrant of its graph. If I'm approximating some smooth function using an Orlicz space I could do so piecewise with upslope regions (positive $x$) and downslope regions (negative $x$) being stitched together at inflection points like you might do with cubic splines.

Comment: If $\phi=x^p$, then this is recovering $L^p$ spaces, and for this to be a useful generalization, we should be getting a number of the common properties that $L^p$ spaces have.  If you can answer "Why do people only like to work with $L^p$ spaces with $p\geq 1$, then you can probably get a good way towards answering "why might we demand convexity?"

Comment: As much I know we consider $L^P$ spaces with $p\geq1$ because we want to define the norm on $L^p$ space and for $0\le p<1$ the norm will not follow the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can always define a space using any choice of $\phi$, it's just a question of what the properties of that space will have. For some $\phi$ it will be a space with many nice properties, for example when $\phi(x) = x^2$ it induces a Hilbert space which makes life very easy. For other $\phi$ you will have a space with essentially no standard structures which will make working in the space very difficult.

The main reason that you want $\phi$ to have the four properties listed is to ensure that
$$||f||_\phi \triangleq \inf \left \{ t > 0:\int_A \phi\left (\frac{|f|}{t} \right ) d\nu \leq 1\right \}$$
defines a norm on the vector space $L^\phi$. In turn, this makes $L^\phi$ a normed vector space (and if you can get completeness too, then it's a [Banach Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space)). Having a norm makes life much easier in many settings.

This is closely related to the idea of the [Minkowski Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) and the norm that it can provide, in the sense that the conditions you provide ensure that the set $K$ that defines the Minkowski functional will be guaranteed to be convex.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.Can you explain more about why those properties are important,how does it affect the way we defined the norm?

Comment: Also here if we want those four properties to be satisfied then we have a function like $\phi(x)=|x|^p  where, 1<p<\infty$.can you give some other example for $\phi(x)$.

Comment: The most famous other two functions are $e^{|x|} - 1$ and $e^{|x|^2} - 1$ and these are used to define the so-called "sub-exponential" and "sub-gaussian" norms.